# Understanding Score column in ml.net regression

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, ml.net

I am following this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/predict-prices) from Microsoft docs for linear regression using ML.Net. I am not able to determine why exactly do we need a class with a score column with the specific column name as '**Score**'. I tried changing the column name from Score to something else which results in the following exception: 
[image]

The classes I have declared for my Input and predictions are as follows:

```
public class TaxiTrip {
    // All the columns inclusive of the label column
    [LoadColumn(0)]
    public string VendorId;

    [LoadColumn(1)]
    public string RateCode;

    [LoadColumn(2)]
    public float PassengerCount;

    [LoadColumn(3)]
    public float TripTime;

    [LoadColumn(4)]
    public float TripDistance;

    [LoadColumn(5)]
    public string PaymentType;

    [LoadColumn(6)]
    public float FareAmount;
}

public class TaxiTripFarePrediction {
    [ColumnName("PredictionScore")]
    public float FareAmount;
}
```

Also as I never specified the class `TaxiTripFarePrediction` anywhere either in the training function or in the Evaluate function as shown above how does the model work when I specify the column name as `Score` instead of something else?

The similar scenario was seen for the `Label` column.

Answer (score 1):

The `TaxiTripFarePrediction` class represents predicted results. It has a single float field, `FareAmount`, with a `Score` attribute applied. In case of the regression task, the **Score** column contains predicted label values.

I'm new in ML and I think Score and Features cannot change the properties. You can refer this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-does-mldotnet-work#mlnet-architecture

You can see this image. Score and Features are generated by algorithms
[image]